# Vertically align element inside of a floating div with no known height

Tags: html, css

I'm aware that there does exist solutions for vertical alignment but the issue is there are all sorts of ways to accomplish this but I haven't found one which deals with a flex container. And many solutions revolve around having a fixed height which doesn't help me at all since my height is always unknown.

I would like to vertically align the element inside of my left floating div which is the **.about_container .welcome** div block. How can I figure this out, and feel free to point out any bad practices that I may have used in my code.

If you want to see what the output of the follow two files look like, I've added a screen shot of the output on the bottom.

**Contents of my HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CSS Maddness</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="floatHelp.css">
</head>
<body>
         <div class="about_container">
            <div class="welcome">
               <h1>Welcome<br>to my<br>Webpage!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="welcome_content">
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.  </p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="projects">
            <h2>Some lonely text down here to test against overflow.</h2>
         </div>
      </div>
<body>
</html>
```

**Contents of my CSS file**

```
.about_container { 
   color: snow;
   display: flex;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.about_container .welcome {
   background-color: #DCC7AA; 
   float: left;
   margin 0;
   width: 50%;
   -webkit-flex: 1; 
   -moz-flex: 1
   -ms-flex: 1; 
   flex: 1;
}

.about_container .welcome_content { 
   background-color: #F7882F; 
   margin: 0px;
   top: 0;
   float: right;
   width: 50%;
   -webkit-flex: 1; 
   -moz-flex: 1
   -ms-flex: 1; 
   flex: 1;
}

.about_container .welcome_content p{ 
   padding: 15px;
}

.about_container .welcome h1 {
   border: 3px solid snow;
   border-radius: 10px; 
   font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
   margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
}

#projects{
   clear: both;
}
```

**Output:**
[The element in my left div is not vertically centered as you can see from this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE3pS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following parameters to `.about_container .welcome h1`

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
```

and add `position: relative` to `.about_container .welcome`

```css
.about_container {
  color: snow;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.about_container .welcome {
  background-color: #DCC7AA;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -moz-flex: 1 -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
.about_container .welcome_content {
  background-color: #F7882F;
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -moz-flex: 1 -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
.about_container .welcome_content p {
  padding: 15px;
}
.about_container .welcome h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
  border: 3px solid snow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#projects {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="about_container">
  <div class="welcome">
    <h1>Welcome<br>to my<br>Webpage!</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="welcome_content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="projects">
  <h2>Some lonely text down here to test against overflow.</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This option is safer then the answer. In terms of browser compatibility.

Comment: Yeah, this one is really good too, I just went with the other one for fewer lines and I'm self learning html & css. I wish I could accept multiple answers. Sadly, my +1 doesn't count since my reputation isn't high enough yet.

Comment: @magreenberg Feel free to vote it up ;-)  But actually, the question already contains flexbox, so the other solution works as well.

Comment: I wish I could accept both. They are both really good. Thank you jacob and Johannes.

Answer (score 1):

Just make `.about_container .welcome` a `flex` container too. Add this to the `.about_container .welcome` rule:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```